# Локализация игрового меню

Tags: c#, unity3d, unity3d-ui

Всем привет, у меня сейчас игра на eng языке хочу добавить ru язык. Подскажите хороший способ локализации игрового меню.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В юнити есть локализейшн менеджер для этих целей:

https://unity3d.com/learn/tutorials/topics/scripting/localization-manager

Так же есть готовый бесплатный ассет:
https://assetstore.unity.com/packages/tools/localization/lean-localization-28504

а еще есть:
https://assetstore.unity.com/packages/tools/localization/translation-system-i18n-plugin-languages-59716 -- В нем можно задавать локалицацию через интерфейс и через CSV файлы.

А еще можно посмотреть вот этот линк для просмотра всех ассетов касающихся перевода: https://assetstore.unity.com/categories/tools/localization

Comment: Спасибо большое)