# Unity: выпадающий список переменных в Inspector

Tags: c#, unity3d

Делаю для игры перевод на разные языки. В первом скрипте есть публичный класс с публичными переменными

```
public static lang lng = new lang();

public class lang
{
    public string language;
    public string[] trainingTap;

}
```

Стал делать второй скрипт "Translator", который вешается на каждый обьект с текстом. Подскажите, как сделать так, что бы в инспекторе можно было из этого скрипта сделать выпадающий список с публичными переменными другого скрипта? Что то вроде того, как на прилагающейся картинке. Пытался связаться с автором видео, безуспешно[image: выпадающий список]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

тот дропдаун который ты прилепил на скриншоте -- это банальный Enum.
Энамы в инспекторе отображаются именно так.

```
enum myEnum
{
  Item1, 
  Item2, 
  Item3
};

public myEnum DropDown = myEnum.Item1;//будет отображатся как дропдаун
```

Но раз уж ты затронул вопрос о переводе, то я бы советовал не лепить собственные велосипеды, а погуглить ассеты платные или бесплатные которые это реализуют по запросу "unity localization"

Вот в этом вопросе я давал пару полезных линков по теме: [Локализация игрового меню](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/914994/%d0%9b%d0%be%d0%ba%d0%b0%d0%bb%d0%b8%d0%b7%d0%b0%d1%86%d0%b8%d1%8f-%d0%b8%d0%b3%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%b3%d0%be-%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd%d1%8e/915019#915019)

Comment: Подскажите, а как в этом самом Enum'е сделать ссылку на публичные переменные из моего public static класса "lng"? циклом пройтись?

Comment: Я не понимаю что такое ссылка на публичные переменные в даном контексте. Окроме того я настоятельно советую, все же, не изобретать свой велосипед. Ты все равно упустишь очень много вещей при реализации перевода. И все равно прийдешь к тем же системам что уже существуют, просто в своей реализации.Потому, что в одном случае ты не учтешь особенности одного письмописания и на нем все завалится, на другой на другом.... Или хотя бы наперед посмотри где люди запинаются когда пишут i18n у себя, раз все равно хочешь писать сам.

Comment: Все, разобрался, ваш ответ оказался исчерпывающим. И я не изобретаю велосипед, я делаю практически как в вашей линке, тот же json.

Answer (score 2):

Для этих целей вам нужно написать кастомный скрипт для инспектора вашего компонента(скрипта), а в нем использовать `EditorGUILayout.Popup()` метод, который позволяет сделать выпадающий список и принимает как параметр массив строк.

Пример из [документации](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/EditorGUILayout.Popup.html) по этому методу выглядит похожим на то, что вы хотите:

```
using UnityEditor;
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class EditorGUILayoutPopup : EditorWindow
{
    //Массив строк, которые хотим видеть в выпадающем списке
    public string[] options = new string[] {"Cube", "Sphere", "Plane"};
    public int index = 0;
    [MenuItem("Examples/Editor GUILayout Popup usage")]
    static void Init()
    {
        EditorWindow window = GetWindow(typeof(EditorGUILayoutPopup));
        window.Show();
    }

    void OnGUI()
    {
        index = EditorGUILayout.Popup(index, options);
        if (GUILayout.Button("Create"))
            InstantiatePrimitive();
    }
}
```

Что будет выглядеть вот так:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]